# Obtain UID and KEY from Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently trying to theorise then write a web app that will make use of the Facebook API to let a user login. From here I want to gain access to the uid and key so I can then populate the following link:

```
http://www.facebook.com/ical/b.php?uid=xxxxxxx&key=xxxxxxx
```

Which gives me the Icalendar file of that users friends birthdays for the whole year. Then hoping to script this into a better format such as CSV and place in a database.

This is all so I can create an import of all your friends birthdays and setup a process from here.

I'd just like to know if I can use the Login to Facebook button to retrieve the parameters to populate my link? Is that possible or is there a better way to get these attributes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to request the `friends_birthday` permission when [authenticate your user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication) and make this [Graph API Call](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cbirthday)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=name,birthday
```

You'll get a json object back with the uid, name, and birthday (if they've populated / made public that field) for each of your friends.